# What skill(s) to use to craft and place explosives?

Tags: skills, crafting, genesys

What skill(s) to use to craft and place explosives?  Is that a new intelligence - Knowledge skill I would need to create or is it an existing one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mechanics (Intellect)

> Your Character Should Use This Skill If[...]
>
> - Your character needs to sabotage an enemy's vehicle or find a weak point in their defenses.
> - Your character needs to build an item or modify it.
>
> -- "General Skills", *Genesis Core Rulebook* p.81

The exceptions called out for mechanics are cybernetics (which may need a joint Medicine check) and anything that needs extensive programming (which needs a Computers check). Explosives aren't either of these.

**Inventing** new types of explosives would be a Knowledge check, as would understanding a novel type of explosive, but manufacturing explosives through a known process is Mechanics. Making use of general-purpose explosives on the dramatic scale -- that is, when you must be precise in time or effect -- is also Mechanics. Setting an explosive trap you don't want other people to find is more a matter for Skullduggery.

I wouldn't recommend demanding two Mechanics checks to craft an explosive for purpose and also use it for that purpose, outside of a scenario where you wind up with a strongly split result on the first roll. Fail with a bunch of advantages and you'll need to actually do it live, redoing the roll with boost dice = 1/2 advantages. Succeed with a bunch of threat and you'll need to fine-tune it live with a (hopefully lower!) difficulty = 1/2 threat.